# My x and y axis are not readable. How can I fix a unit of measure on the axis?

Tags: image, plot, scatter-plot, axis

I have a little problem with my plot. Since I have so many values, how can I make the x and y axis readable? I'd like to fix a unit of measure on the axis. How can I sort it out?

Thank you!

```
plt.scatter (mstar, sfr, color ='pink')
plt.xlabel('logmass')
plt.ylabel('logSFR')
plt.show()
```

Data on the x axis (mstar) are: ['10.52', '9.473', '9.195', '10.11', '9.589', '10.19', '9.374', '10.05', '10.23', '10.74', '10.61', '9.36', '9.595', '10.92', '9.479', '9.549', '10.68', '10.74', '10.31', '8.264', '8.665', '8.712', '9.203', '8.914', '9.81', '10.54', '10.13', '9.81', '9.87', '9.86', '9.27', '9.08', '8.78', '9.62', '9.23', '9.22', '10.53', '10.11', '10.32', '9.22', '10.02', '10.07', '9.16', '9.51', '9.74', '9.28', '9.31', '9.96', '9.91', '9.49', '9.27', '9.26', '8.96', '8.75', '7.49', '8.9', '9.2', '9.46', '9.12', '8.69', '7.39', '9.18', '9.75', '8.53', '8.47', '10.01', '9.82', '10.42', '9.65', '10.32', '10.37', '9.4', '10.89', '11.34']

Data on the y axis (sfr) are: ['0.6388', '-0.3744', '-0.4425', '-0.9009', '-0.9664', '0.05949', '-0.6335', '0.2962', '-0.2829', '0.3167', '-0.9527', '-0.5869', '-1.206', '0.3683', '-1.68', '-0.7564', '-0.4969', '0.113', '0.2508', '-1.284', '-1.755', '-2.918', '-0.5734', '-2.139', '0.1038', '-0.04576', '0.4784', '-0.9566', '0.2647', '0.7604', '0.02648', '0.1613', '-0.8109', '-0.01967', '-0.5942', '-0.1827', '0.2047', '0.6062', '-0.1293', '0.2303', '-1.000', '0.08164', '0.09781', '0.302', '0.00731', '0.09938', '-0.08674', '0.02707', '0.3765', '0.01095', '0.1501', '-0.06735', '-0.3979', '-1.0451', '-99', '-0.3586', '-0.5735', '-0.2420', '-99', '-0.5021', '-99', '-0.1549', '-0.2982', '-0.6214', '-1.2541', '-0.3312', '0.06567', '-0.6579', '0.5253', '0.6939', '0.2118', '0.2838', '0.4153', '-0.3508']

The plot is here. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quY3I.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting the width and height

```
width = 8
height = 6
plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
```